# React list items with keys re-mounting

Tags: reactjs, react-window

I have a React project with some fairly large lists. It has gotten to the point where it has had a detrimental effect on performance and I've decided to virtualize them using [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window). The conversion was simple, but I've run into an issue where any change to my list items (list size, item property change, anything...) always causes all list items to re-mount (not just re-render).

I haven't had the time to break this out into a reproducible case, as the application is huge, but I've made the following observations:

- All list items have a `key`, and this is verified via the React Developer Tools.
- When an item changes in the list, all `keys` remain exactly the same.
- When using a plain `map` to render the list items, they don't re-mount upon any change.
- When using `react-window` with the same exact list items, they all re-mount upon any change.
- The parent List component does *not* re-mount on change (only re-renders).

This has led me to believe it is react-window that is causing the re-mounting, but all examples online do not exhibit this behavior. In reported issues where this does seem to be the case, it is usually concluded that the developer is not providing a `key` for their items, or is using the `key` incorrectly.

When questions like this are asked, people are typically inclined to respond with an answer addressing that they need to stop using an Anonymous function as their item, use React.memo, implement componentDidUpdate, etc... *But this is not the issue I'm dealing with*. I have component re-rendering under control. It is the fact that **the items are all re-mounting even though they all have keys and the keys don't change**.

Since I don't have a code snippet to provide, my primary question is: **What scenarios might lead React to re-mount a list item that always retains the same key?**

Comment: hard to say without code snippet. But one case can be that the root of this component containing then the list with keys, changes completely the type, then the diff algorithm thinks it is all a new element, and renders by new all the node

Comment: It seems like a `react-window` bug. Other possibility is that your mail list component is being re-mounted due to some reason. I would suggest, use your own solution, break down list component to achieve maximum performance